# Video keeps playing when switching image or video in gallery

Tags: aframe

I’m a 3D motion designer, just started learning A-frame a few months ago, I work with a lot of 360 video and i wanted to put together a simple gallery showcasing what I’ve done.

The issue is when you start a video, change the image, the video still runs in the background. Is there some way I can get it to stop when changing images? You can check it out here. https://bechtelmgfx.com/360gallery/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a bug described [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3615). When changing sources, the video element created [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.9.0/src/systems/material.js#L359) seems to be kind of forgotten.

I'd suggest using the `<a-assets>` - so you can manually pause the video:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
     <video id='vid' autoplay='true' src="sample-video.mp4">
     </video>
  </a-assets>
  <a-image position="0 0 -4" width="5" height="5" src="#vid></a-image>
</a-scene>
```

now, whenever you need, just `pause()` the video element, and change the source to an image. Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3zf1v6xy/).